# JSON is invalid (JSONview), but I don't see how

Tags: php, json, json-view

OK, I've been going nuts with this. I'm outputting a JSON from PHP, and the JSON View extension, for both Chrome and Firefox, is claiming it's invalid. Both extensions work correctly on [JSON View's example](http://jsonview.com/example.json), so it seems likely that there actually *is* something wrong with my JSON – but I have no idea what.

The Firefox version has an error message:

```
There was an error parsing the JSON document. The document may not be well-formed.
```

The Chrome version lacks such error messages, but still prints the JSON as plaintext.

I *am* setting the header, like so: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` I've checked the response header in Firebug and Chrome's development tools; it is correctly set in both cases. Removing that hides the error message in the Firefox version and the plaintext is not in a monospace font, but that's it.

Complete request headers:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:msgPublishID=1347362550,1345649049; logout_rem=1; sh_rand=625703e7f9f9e03efabaef56f52ff97d7f68bc67; username=kryan; password=f85720746a490ece4dd7a945f5c9ed8e25b15f1f; fullname=Kevin+Ryan; user_type=1
Host:localhost
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
```

Complete response headers:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:371
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 27 Sep 2012 19:12:52 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.4
```

I've gone through many variations on the JSON itself, but I can't imagine that it's the JSON's problem when something as simple as this:

```
{"session":"expired"}
```

is still failing. I've checked repeatedly; that is literally the entirety of the server's response, but JSON View still complains. For more complicated JSONs, I've been using

```
echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

where `$output` is an associative array; the output looks completely right but JSON View is still complaining. This is the only `echo` in the file that isn't commented out.

So what on earth could be going wrong here? I really need JSON View; I work with very large JSONs constantly and the ability to collapse and expand objects and arrays is critical to debugging my application. [This online JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) seems to work, but my productivity is going to take a hit if I have to copy and paste the output of these PHP files every time I'm testing them.

EDIT: One thing I have found that works is if I do this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    die('{"debug":true}');
    // remainder of the program as-is, starting with...
    require('dbinfo.php');
```

If I then go with this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    require('dbinfo.php'); // note this comes before the die statement
    die('{"debug":true}');
    // remainder of the program as-is
```

I get the error again.

So this implies that `dbinfo.php` is causing the problem.

EDIT: Sorry, I've removed `dbinfo.php` from this question because it might possibly contain sensitive data that should not be public (even though I stripped out the obvious things). Since the *content* of `dbinfo.php` wasn't relevant, it just seems safer to remove it. See my answer below.

Comment: Could you please provide the additional HTTP headers being sent back and forth for the request and the response?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your error log? Have you checked firebug or something to see the headers being sent to the browser? Only thing I can think of is if something inadvertently was already sent so headers can't be modified.

Comment: what are you using on the client side to parse the json string?

Comment: @LiorCohen: Sure, added those in. Let me know if anything else is relevant.

Comment: @Pitchinnate: As I said in the question originally, yes, I have checked in Firebug that the headers are being sent to the browser and appear to be received.

Comment: @Flosculus: Again, as stated in the question originally, I'm using the JSON View extension for Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I have JSON view on chrome and i used this 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $array = array(
        'session' => 'expired',
    );
    echo json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
and it works fine. So not sure what the issue would be.

Comment: What does your packet sniffer say?

Comment: @Pitchinnate: Yes, sorry if that was unclear: I doubt it's the content of the JSON that's causing problems. I posted the content to try to demonstrate why I believe this. What I'm hoping to discover is what *else* could cause this.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Don't have one/have never used one. Can you recommend one/give quick tips on how to use one? I don't really know a lot of details about networks.

Comment: @KRyan: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: Have you verified the _content_ of your replies in Firebug/Devtools, as opposed to just checking your PHP code? Since requiring `dbinfo.php` breaks the JSON display, I suspect your script dies before producing the actual JSON output.

Comment: @lanzz: Of course I have. For that matter, the output to the screen, even though not pretty printed by JSON View, is all there.

Comment: Can you `curl -i <url>` or `wget -qSO <url>` and add the full output received to your question?

Comment: @lanzz: I figured out the problem, so I don't think I will, but I was wondering: can you do those things from a Windows machine?

Comment: Both have Windows binaries: [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32), [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). Just in case it's not clear, those are command-line tools, you will be running them in `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh.

I figured it out: the BOM was screwing things up, but of course it was also being completely invisible. Checking and changing the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM fixed the problem entirely.

I don't know if this BOM thing is a problem with PHP's design or Unicode's design, but it is certainly obnoxious.